# How to use "term" filter properly in ElasticSearch?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

i use elasticsearch in my code (Python 3.6):

```
result_search = es.search(index="area", body={
                "query": { 
                    "bool": { 
                    
                    "filter": [ 
                        { "term":  { "country_id": "ID" }}
                    ]
                    }
                }
                })
```

but it returns

```
{'took': 0,
 'timed_out': False,
 '_shards': {'total': 1, 'successful': 1, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0},
 'hits': {'total': {'value': 0, 'relation': 'eq'},
  'max_score': None,
  'hits': []}}
```

in the data, there is "ID" in country_id field

what's my mistake ?

if i change "term" with "match" it return something (not zero result) , but i want to use "term" because i want to filter exact value only

python elasticsearch

Comment: sample data in doc? are you searching id or ID?

Comment: {'country_id': 'ID',
  'city_id': 'ID-BAD',
  'city_name': 'Denpasar'}

Comment: what is the field type for country_id? did you set any?

Comment: no, i dont set any type

Comment: You can also use the `country_id.keyword` field to match exactly using a `term` query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used `text` field with `default analyzer`.

Hence `ID` will be stored as `id` in the index. You can confirm by `http://host:port/indexName/_analyze` API.

`Term` queries are not `full text search` queries means they are not analyzed. Whereas `match` queries are full text queries.

So when you search `ID`, it expects `ID` in the index. So it is not returning anything when you use term.

So you need to set `mapping` to use `term` queries. Set `keyword` for `country_id`. Then it will not be analysed and will be stored as you added while writing. Then same can be searched.

OR

You can use `default keyword` version of field while querying - `country_id.keyword` for term queries and `country_id` for match queries.